# Вывод миниатюры изображения, вставленного в запись со стороннего ресурса

Tags: wordpress

Как выводить на главной странице в списке новостей превью изображения, которое вставлено в запись ссылкой со стороннего ресурса?

В записи оно отображается, а в списке новостей нет.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: В используемой теме таких функций нет. Есть ли другие способы?

Comment: Их не может не быть. Читай внимательно по ссылке. В тч и описания функций в кодексе.

Answer (score 0):

Решил плагином [Featured Image from URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-from-url/)